# How to Change scrollview alpha value

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I need to decrease and increase the alpha values of labels which are added within a scrollview.
Changing it like this `self.scrolllview.alpha = 0.2f` doesn't work
How do I achieve this ?

Comment: You want to increase/decrease the alpha values of labels than why you are setting the alpha value of scrolllview instead of labels? Try to set alpha value of labels.

Comment: i have 'n' no of labels in the scrollview... i need to loop thru the subviews of my scrollview.. pick one label at a time and change the alpha ?? is this what u suggest...?

Comment: You have 'n' no of labels in the scrollview than how you allocate that labels?  Programatically? If possible than set alpha value of label at the allocation time.

Comment: yup i add the labels programmatically in the view didload

Comment: its has to be done later.... i have another scrollview.... on the scrollview of which i need to fade in and out the other scrollview an its contents

Comment: Than add all that labels in array so when you want to change properties of label fetch from array and than set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `UIScrollView.h`, there is no property like alpha, cause scroll don't need a property to change alpha, set scroll background color white, and set alpha like `UIImageView` or other you add in scroll view. Use this method you can show different alpha in scroll.